# Inconsistent HTTP Errors from Uploading Images with Uploadify and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, uploadify

I'm having great difficulty in finding a bug preventing some uploads to my rails app through Uploadify.

Here is the error I'm receiving:

http://j.imagehost.org/0353/uploadify-errors.png

The thing that's making this difficult is that it's not at all consistent. Sometimes the images will upload perfectly fine. Other times they won't. The same image(s) that fail on one attempt will succeed on another. I really can't understand it, and I can't find any information from the web about it. The problem persists across browsers, operating systems and users. Sometimes it works, other times it doesn't. In any given list of images to be uploaded in one go, it's possible that all will work, all will fail, or some will work and the rest fail.

I've updated all the related software to latest releases (except Rails, running 2.3.4 there). Paperclip and Uploadify are running latest releases.

If anyone has any advice on where I need to start looking I'd really appreciate it. If you need any other information from me, just let me know what and I'll get it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with uploadify, it worked perfectly on the local machine, but did not work on prod machine (nginx + passenger), when I viewed the nginx error log file, I saw this error:
"2011/02/22 06:08:37 [error] 9545#0: *1312823 client intended to send too large body: 2400765 bytes"

I added "client_max_body_size 4m;" to nginx.conf, it fixed the http errors, hopefully it will work for you.

I recommend this jquery plugin http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload (no flash require)

I am using it ;)

Comment: That jquery plugin is nice! HTML5 for those that support it, with a nice fallback for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The actual http error will be shown in the console, or in the logs, so take a look there.